# How do I disable the 30 second delay on Remote Desktop connections to Windows 7 when a user is logged in?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, delay

I just installed Windows 7 on my laptop.  I want to be able to log in using RDC quickly.  If I failed to log out or disconnect prior to walking away from my laptop, when I attempt a RDC connection it pops a confirmation dialog up on the laptop and won't connect the RDC connection for 30 seconds unless the confirmation dialog is used.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Why is your laptop terminating the connection when you walk away in the first place? Does RDC terminate when the screen locks?

Comment: @Will: I think he's talking about walking away from his laptop and then RDC-ing into it from another place.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message or a screenshot of the confirmation dialog?

Comment: You should nto have accepted an answer (from 'user8228'), that clearly didn't solve it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using *Local Group Policy Editor* (gpedit.msc) there is a setting under :

```
Administrative Templates \ Windows components \ Remote desktop services \ Remote desktop session host \  Connections
```

saying "**Set rules of remote control of remote desktop services**" witch lets you specify the interaction mode and the control level for an RDP session

enable it and choose the "**Full control without user permission**" option. so the logged user won't be prompt for confirmation (there is more details there)

you can also set the **Session time limit for active but idle RDP service** under **session time limit** folder to "**Never**" and it won't disconnect you you IDLE.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part... I did not find "session time limit" anywhere. Instead I found a folder called "session time limits", but the settings there are not exactly what I am looking for. What I want is to change the 30 second to larger value. Is this possible?

Comment: @juha i've edited my answer. you looked into the right place (session time limit folder), you need to enable that setting and then look under the "Options" label and set the "time limit" to any other value.

Comment: In that folder there are a bunch of options "set time limit for disconnected sessions", "set time limit for active but idle remote desktop services sessions", "set time limit for active remote desktop services sessions", "end session when time limits are reached".   It's not clear which if any of those are the right option

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft Support article :
[Remote Desktop Connection 6.0 prompts you for credentials before you establish a remote desktop connection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941641/en-us)
suggests turning off this message by text-editing the .rdp file and changing the value of authentication level to zero, like that:

> authentication level:i:0

Comment: This can't be right. The question asked about 30 second delay, I don't think this answer is right..I tested, (albeit not on win7), but on win10, and it doesn't change that. Also the MS article says nothinn about 30 seconds. And it wouldn't make sense for the client computer to be able to set that anyway..  It's talking about an option of logging out the other user that is connected to the server.

Comment: @barlop: This answer is from 2009. Sorry if it no longer works, but it's too far ago for me to look into it. You could start a new post for Windows 10 and drop me a note (if I can help).

Comment: JohnT already posted a solution (in 2009).. But my point isn't that your post would work in windows 7 but not windows 10. Even putting aside Windows 10. My point is that I don't think your post could possibly work even for Windows 7. (And I don't see reason to think there's a difference between windows version in relation to this either but that's another matter). If it's too far for you to look into it to check if it works re the windows version asked about in the question (win7), then fine. But i'm just saying and giving the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script to check if the window is open periodically. Without an image of the comfirmation dialog, I don't know the exact text, but you can substitute it in my script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow
loop 
{
    IfWinExist, Remote Desktop Connection Disconnected ; modify this
        Send { Enter }
    else
    {
    Sleep 1000 ; wait a second, save our CPU
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a Windows Server 2012 machine. After trying many other approaches, I tried the one suggested by John T and got it to work. It's somewhat different, probably because of the Metro interface and/or the secure desktop that the popup dialog runs in. It's not able to interact by window title (which is "Remote Desktop Connection"), so I have it detect the process and then send enter.

```
; Wait for the "Remote Desktop Connection" process to popup and automatically cancel
; must use PID matching on sessionmsg.exe because IfWinExist didn't work (secure desktop?)
loop 
{
    Process, wait, sessionmsg.exe, 2
    NewPID = %ErrorLevel%  ; Save the value immediately since ErrorLevel is often changed.
    if NewPID = 0
    {
        Sleep 1000 ; wait a second, save our CPU
    }
    else
    {
        Send { Enter }
        Sleep 10000 ; it takes sessionmsg.exe several seconds to exit
    }
}
```