# Modify 30 second wait period when RDP'ing to computer with user already logged in

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, group-policy, terminal-services

In Windows 7, when remotely connecting to a workstation that already has a user logged in, it prompts the local user that someone is trying to connect and offers them 30 seconds to deny access. I would like to modify that time and bump it up to 60 or 120 seconds.

This guy talks about doing something similar, but doesn't exactly explain how he did it: [How to prevent remote desktop login when user is logged in locally?](https://superuser.com/questions/321866/how-to-prevent-remote-desktop-login-when-user-is-logged-in-locally)

Does anyone know how to modify that time limit? I do not want to disable the ability to remote when someone else is logged in (I know how to do that via group policy). I just want to give the local user more time before I kick them off. There are scenarios when 30 seconds might not be enough time for the user to see the message and press cancel.

Additionally, I found that string 1502 in termsrv.dll controls the message given to the local user when someone is trying to connect. I haven't tried this yet,  but if I modify that string to read 120 seconds instead of 30 seconds, it MIGHT do the trick. Or it might just change the message that is displayed to the user, but still in fact only count down to 30 though.

Thanks!

Comment: Modifying that string in the DLL is unlikely to have any positive effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable the 30 second delay on Remote Desktop connections to Windows 7 when a user is logged in?](http://superuser.com/questions/33815/how-do-i-disable-the-30-second-delay-on-remote-desktop-connections-to-windows-7)

Comment: Was a little too fast there with the duplicate suggestion. Might still be relevant reading material though.