# Windows 10: How to reduce the 30 second wait time for Remote Desktop connections?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I want to reduce that time to 5 seconds. So when somebody tries to connect to my PC and I am away from my desktop, they do not take more than 5 seconds to log in.

**added by barlop**

This is what the OP is talking about

[image]

Comment: It is 30 sec for me, is it maybe a group policy created by the university where I work? I am administrator of the machine

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT you haven't understood what he is referring to. He's referring to a specific 30 second wait. See my pic

Comment: @barlop Okay, thanks for the edit and clarifying for the OP, I definitely didn't understand I suppose in the context of the question before your edit. Good job!

Comment: @barlop I looked around at a bunch of other various answers and don't see much out there. I noticed you've hit some comments up on some, so I assume you're looking for a solution to this yourself. As a workaround I've used on Windows 10 although it's been a few versions back, I wrote about it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1008656/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-logoff-after-closing-the-connection/1012572#1012572 .... I know there is debate on legality depending on your country, interpretation, etc. I can confirm it worked for me in the past allowing concurrent RDP session on Window 10.

Comment: Nonetheless, you've spiked my interest in knowing of a real solution to that pop up and functionality. I think this may be a good question worthy of a new write up being detailed and specific more than other questions and being specific for the type of desired solution needed. I think that'd be more appropriate than bounty on existing question as if there's not much out there, it's waiting for a good write up I think.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT the superuser legend, JohnT (the guy whose rep shot up like coronavirus in a very short time, then vanished), wrote an answer that works for Win7 https://superuser.com/questions/33815/how-do-i-disable-the-30-second-delay-on-remote-desktop-connections-to-windows-7   Win10 would be a question. (also some solutions not mentioned here might be a bit underground and of questionable legality like some google results speak of patching or effectively patching termsrv.dll and an annoying cat and mouse game with MS) and solutions can break any time windows updates

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT  the famous raymond blogger mentions something about that (though doesn't mention anything re legality, just that it's annoying MS keeps breaking it) https://www.raymond.cc/blog/enable-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-7-home-premium/ Also, I heard that server editions might be OK with simultaneous connections (best solution and with other benefits, might be to switch to only use server editions of their OS) ;-)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT you may find this interesting, https://superuser.com/questions/1548272/difficulty-installing-rdpwrap-on-windows-10-to-get-multiple-remote-desktop-conn/1548312   RDP Wrapper

Comment: @barlop Looks like the exact tool from my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1008656/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-logoff-after-closing-the-connection/1012572#1012572 right? It seems one of the links from my answer points to the github you are using. I'm going to read over your new post with more detail now though. Good job finding a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think this only occurs when there is a active session already: see:

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3205899/disable-wait-time-remote-desktop-connections.html

The only other settings I know of are the security settings; though they can be found using Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) there is a setting under :

Administrative Templates \ Windows components \ Remote desktop services \ Remote desktop session host \  Connections

more information here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/292190/how-to-shadow-a-terminal-server-session-without-prompt-for-approval 
and here
https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=158387.0

Comment: I don't think there is such an option. If you think there is then please include a picture