# difficulty installing rdpwrap on windows 10 (to get multiple remote desktop connections)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

RDP Wrap helps to allow for multiple connections to remote desktop on eg Windows 7 or Windows 10.  I tried to install rdpwrap going to https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/ and I tried running the MSI under "releases", RDPWInst-v1.6.2.msi and it gave some error, and when I tried to reinstall it and I got no error and it wasn't clear what i'm meant to run or what if anything was intalled. And no concurrent/simultaneous remote desktop either.

Then I tried to uninstall it and it prompted me to allow c:\windows\installer\c4d5253.msi to run. I said yes. And it said "There is a problem with this windows installer package".

Note- I have a solution and will post an answer.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, I've been using 2X/Parallels Client (And Recently discovered Remmina for Linux and it's the best) and used to use Microsoft's RDP MMC Console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/ there are three ways one may try to download the program. There's downloading the code, from the code tab. Or, under the releases tab, there's downloading the MSI file. Or, also under the releases tab, there's downloading the zip.

Out of those methods, the method I used that worked, was to go to the releases tab, and download the Zip there. So, not the code tab, not that zip. And not the MSI under releases. But the zip under releases.  RDPWrap-v1.6.2.zip

Then, extract that zip to some directory. Start a cmd prompt run as administrator. So an administrative cmd prompt. (from there you can run install.bat  that's better than being in a regular cmd prompt and right clicking install.bat and doing runas on the bat, 'cos apparently that can be buggy).

Extracting the zip produces

```
C:\rdpwrap>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C811-E477

 Directory of C:\rdpwrap

03/05/2020  15:34    <DIR>          .
03/05/2020  15:34    <DIR>          ..
03/05/2020  15:34               458 install.bat
03/05/2020  15:34         1,045,504 RDPCheck.exe
03/05/2020  15:34         1,096,192 RDPConf.exe
03/05/2020  15:34         1,460,224 RDPWInst.exe
03/05/2020  15:34               249 uninstall.bat
03/05/2020  15:34               249 update.bat
               6 File(s)      3,602,876 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  440,941,117,440 bytes free

C:\rdpwrap>
```

You needn't run RDPWinst.exe directly, the bat files run it with the right switches/options.

Run install.bat from an administrative cmd prompt

```
C:\rdpwrap>install
RDP Wrapper Library v1.6.2
Installer v2.5
Copyright (C) Stas'M Corp. 2017

[*] Notice to user:
  - By using all or any portion of this software, you are agreeing
  to be bound by all the terms and conditions of the license agreement.
  - To read the license agreement, run the installer with -l parameter.
  - If you do not agree to any terms of the license agreement,
  do not use the software.
[*] Installing...
[*] Terminal Services version: 10.0.17134.706
[-] This version of Terminal Services is not supported.
Try running "update.bat" or "RDPWInst -w" to download latest INI file.
If it doesn't help, send your termsrv.dll to project developer for support.
[+] TermService found (pid 8592).
[*] No shared services found.
[*] Extracting files...
[+] Folder created: C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\
[*] Downloading latest INI file...
[+] Latest INI file -> C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.ini
[+] Extracted rdpw64 -> C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.dll
[*] Configuring service library...
[*] Checking dependencies...
[*] Checking CertPropSvc...
[*] Checking SessionEnv...
[*] Terminating service...
[*] Starting TermService...
[*] Configuring registry...
[*] Configuring firewall...
Ok.

[+] Successfully installed.
______________________________________________________________

You can check RDP functionality with RDPCheck program.
Also you can configure advanced settings with RDPConf program.

Press any key to continue . . .

C:\rdpwrap>
```

A major thing that did is made this directory and these files

```
C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.ini
C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.dll
```

You can run uninstall.bat but then you'd have to run install.bat again

```
C:\rdpwrap>uninstall
RDP Wrapper Library v1.6.2
Installer v2.5
Copyright (C) Stas'M Corp. 2017

[*] Uninstalling...
[+] TermService found (pid 3340).
[*] No shared services found.
[*] Resetting service library...
[*] Terminating service...
[*] Removing files...
[+] Removed file: C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.ini
[+] Removed file: C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.dll
[+] Removed folder: C:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\
[*] Starting TermService...
[*] Configuring registry...
[*] Configuring firewall...

Deleted 1 rule(s).
Ok.

[+] Successfully uninstalled.

Press any key to continue . . .

C:\rdpwrap>
```

But you want it installed so run install.bat

So you have those two files now in \program files\rdp wrap

You could try

```
C:\rdpwrap\rdpconf
```

That will tell you if your version of `c:\windows\system32\termsrv.dll` (which came with your OS),  is supported by your `c:\program files\rdp wrap\rdpwrap.ini`

See what version your termsrv.dll is  (rdp wrap will not and has not replaced this file).

You can use right click..properties, or as I have for the sake of this post, the command line

```
C:\rdpwrap>wmic datafile where name="c:\\Windows\\System32\\termsrv.dll" get version
Version
10.0.17134.706
```

You can check yourself whether it's supported by your ini file.. either in notepad and edit..find  and see or

```
C:\rdpwrap>find "10.0.17134.706" "c:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.ini"

---------- C:\PROGRAM FILES\RDP WRAPPER\RDPWRAP.INI

C:\rdpwrap>
```

not there

There are some versions there in this case but not my version

C:\rdpwrap>find "10.0.17" "c:\Program Files\RDP Wrapper\rdpwrap.ini"

```
---------- C:\PROGRAM FILES\RDP WRAPPER\RDPWRAP.INI
[10.0.17004.1000]
[10.0.17017.1000]
[10.0.17025.1000]
[10.0.17035.1000]
[10.0.17046.1000]
[10.0.17063.1000]
[10.0.17004.1000-SLInit]
[10.0.17017.1000-SLInit]
[10.0.17025.1000-SLInit]
[10.0.17035.1000-SLInit]
[10.0.17046.1000-SLInit]
[10.0.17063.1000-SLInit]

C:\rdpwrap>
```

rdpconf.exe will say "not supported"

Unfortunately the ini file bundled with the project is old.

There is an update.bat but it gets an old ini file that doesn't support many termsrv.dll versions.

So you have to go to the github page and look at issues or pulls and see if you can get an ini file with your build version in it.

In order to replace `c:\program files\rdp wrap\rdpwrap.ini` you will have to stop  the 'remote desktop services' service, so as to unlock the ini, then replace it, then start it. And you see from services.msc that it's called TermService.  You can do `sc queryex termservice`  to see if it's running or not. s (sc queryex is a bit better than sc query 'cos sc queryex shows pid). And you can do net start termservice, net stop termService, and taskkill it if it gets stuck 'stopping'.

Then you can run rdpconf.exe see if it says successful.. (as opposed to 'not supported'). You could even use rdpconf before (re)starting terminal services

And then you can do rdpcheck, and see if that says "limited connections" , or if it just works.  (or you could test with mstsc, but rdpcheck is very quick to test)

And then you know  and hopefully it will work for you.

Note- There is a telegram group  https://t.me/rdpwrap that can help with any technical issues with it.

Comment: I would include some pictures but have a network issue at the moment

Comment: Nice.... One thing to keep in mind that I noticed in the past when I used this tool successfully, is that is will create a new session per each time you log in but I think there was a reg settings that I set to tell it to only allow reconnection to disconnected session but otherwise I noticed a year or so back when I used it that if you disconnect and then reconnect with that same user via RDP, it'd start yet another new session and not connect to the disconnected one. Easy enough for you to test though.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Interesting. I'll test it once I get normal internet access and aren't just on a mobile hotspot..  Like if UserA logs on from one machine, and then UserA logs on from another machine.. How it deals with it.

Comment: Exactly, regardless of where UserA logs on from, when there is already a session for UserA, I believe it created a new session for UserA regardless whether it was being actively used or disconnected already, so UserA will keep establishing a new session each login unless you set some WindowsTerminal Server/Services type reg setting or logged off UserA before logging back on as UserA. Something like that, I'm sure you'll be able to recreate is easily and see if that's still an issue.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I just did a test. If I am logged in as UserA. And I connect as UserA from another computer, then it either logs the other one out, or doesn't log in. (and that makes sense 'cos having two logins with the same user would be odd, like two people could change the desktop at the same time if that could happen!). So it doesn't allow two users of the same username to log in at the same time.  (cntd)

Comment: As for if two users of different usernames, it logs them in and looking at task manager on the server I can see the users that are logged in. If a user closes their mstsc screen then in task manager it lists that user still but says 'disconnected'. If on the server I try to restart, then it says that "someone else is still using this pc. If you restart now they could lose unsaved work".  I can then log out my current user, log in as them, log them out. Then I can restart.

Comment: Cool, when I tested it was probably back when Windows 10 first came out of beta to the market and version 1511 perhaps. I know if was working to allow the same username concurrent session just as a Windows Terminal Server allows depending on what setting you have set for Terminal Services or Remote Desktop Connections. In any event, it appears it's not a problem in your case and working fine for your needs so no gotchas with the RDP Wrap and Windows 10 versions you are using!!

Answer (score 0):

MS owns GitHub now and that's probably why the project was taken down (I assume it's against their EULA). However, if you stop `termService` service and add this to the `rdpwrapper.ini` file, then restart the service it might work:

```
[10.0.18362.836]
LocalOnlyPatch.x64=1
LocalOnlyOffset.x64=82FC5
LocalOnlyCode.x64=jmpshort
SingleUserPatch.x64=1
SingleUserOffset.x64=0DBFC
SingleUserCode.x64=Zero
DefPolicyPatch.x64=1
DefPolicyOffset.x64=1FE15
DefPolicyCode.x64=CDefPolicy_Query_eax_rcx
SLInitHook.x64=1
SLInitOffset.x64=22DDC
SLInitFunc.x64=New_CSLQuery_Initialize
[10.0.18362.836-SLInit]
bInitialized.x64 =F6A8C
bServerSku.x64 =F6A90
lMaxUserSessions.x64 =F6A94
bAppServerAllowed.x64 =F6A9C
bRemoteConnAllowed.x64=F6AA0
bMultimonAllowed.x64 =F6AA4
ulMaxDebugSessions.x64=F6AA8
bFUSEnabled.x64 =F6AAC
```

via: https://github.com/fre4kyC0de/rdpwrap/issues/37

Comment: are you sure that the project people have forked was taken down?

Comment: I am not. All I know is that this one (which I believe is the original) was taken down: https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/

Comment: It was up at the time I asked the question but I see it is now down

Comment: This one was updated 18 days ago: https://github.com/fre4kyC0de/rdpwrap

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/fre4kyC0de/rdpwrap/issues/40

Comment: Great!!! Works! Thank everybody dealing with this. I am setting it again cca 10 times in 2 years and always get is somehow. This project deserves its own web and this is something I would pay for. I have one home office place with monitors and keyboard etc. and when I bring office computer, I am lost. Moving computers in whole flat or give up big monitor and work on some 10" notebook and damage eyes. Hate Microsoft!

Comment: You could always switch to Ubuntu, which is free and arguably just as feature-rich as Windows (expect for video games, perhaps).

Comment: Also, re: "this is something I would pay for" - that's exactly why MS took down the GH project. They *do* charge for this exact feature in Windows Server: it's called **Remote Desktop Services** (RDS Server, formerly Terminal Server, "term server").

Comment: Had to fix mine again after the latest update (happens pretty much every update, seems like): https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/1137